# How do I implement a constructor and a property on a class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I recently started learning C# and created a bakery project where a person can buy bread or pastry.

My project works just fine but one of the requirements was to use `{ get; set }` and a constructor.

Here is my bread.cs file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bakery.Models
{
    public class Bread
    { 
        // public Bread(int aNumofBread) 
        // {
        //     int numOfBread = aNumofBread;
        // }
 
        public int CalcBread(int numOfBread) 
        {
            int priceOfLoaf = 5;

            if (numOfBread % 3 == 0) 
            {
                return (numOfBread * priceOfLoaf) - ((numOfBread/3) * priceOfLoaf);     
            } 
            else if (numOfBread % 3 == 1)
            {
                return (numOfBread * priceOfLoaf) - ((numOfBread-1)/3 * priceOfLoaf);
            } 
            else if (numOfBread % 3 == 2)  
            {
                return (numOfBread * priceOfLoaf) - ((numOfBread-2)/3 *priceOfLoaf);
            } 
            else 
                return numOfBread * priceOfLoaf;
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see I did not have a constructor in my class.

Here is what my program.cs looks like:

`````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bakery.Models
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

            string bakeryAscii = @"
                          ....
                      .'      `.
                    .' .-'``-._ `.
                    |  / -    - ` |
                    / |'<o>  <o> | \
                    (|    '`    |) 
                      \  -==-  /   
                       `.____.'    
                        |    |     
                  _ _.'`-.__.-'`._/_
                .'| |`-.  /\  .-'| |`.
              _.'   \ \  `'  `'  / /   `._
            { `.    | `-.____.-' |    .' }
            /`. `./ /   __  __   \ \.' .'\
            /   `.| |   /  \/  \   | |.'   \
          (    (  \ \  \      /  / /  )    )
            `.   \  Y|   `.  .'   |Y  /   .'
              \   \ ||_ _ _\/_ _ _|| /   /
              `.  \|'            `|/  .'
        _______/  _ >--------------< _  \______.##._
              ((((_(                )_))))   .##. |
            / ```` `--------------' ''''\   |  | |
            ( Welcome to Bakery! \  |  |-'
            )                             ) `--'
            (          _        _.---.__.-'
            `-.___.--' `------'

        ";
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        Console.WriteLine(bakeryAscii);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.WriteLine("Please [y] to place your order, [m] to view the menu and [n] to exit");

        string  continueAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        if (continueAnswer == "y")  
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many loaves of bread would you like to purchase today?");
            string stringNumOfBread = Console.ReadLine(); 

            int numOfBread = 0;
            bool checkBreadInput = Int32.TryParse(stringNumOfBread, out numOfBread);

            if (checkBreadInput == true) 
            {
                if (numOfBread >= 0 ) 
                {
                    Bread bread = new Bread();
                    int breadPrice = bread.CalcBread(numOfBread);

                    Console.WriteLine("You have bought " + numOfBread + " loaves  of bread for: $" + breadPrice);
                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to buy some Pastry's today? [y] or [n]");

                    string pastryAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

                    if (pastryAnswer == "y") 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of pastry's you would like to buy:");
 
                        string stringNumOfPastry = Console.ReadLine(); 
                        int numOfPastry = 0;

                        bool checkPastryInput = Int32.TryParse(stringNumOfPastry,   out numOfPastry);

                        if (checkPastryInput == true) 
                        {
                            if (numOfPastry >= 0) 
                            {
                                Pastry pastry = new Pastry();
                                int pastryPrice = pastry.CalcPastry(numOfPastry);

                                Console.WriteLine("You have bought " + numOfPastry + " pastry's");
                                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                                int total = breadPrice + pastryPrice;
                                Console.WriteLine("Your total bill is $" + total);

                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
                            } 
                            else 
                                ErrorNegativeNumber(); 
                        } 
                        else 
                            Error();
                    } 
                    else if (pastryAnswer == "n") 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for coming in, your total bill is $" + breadPrice);
                        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
                    } 
                    else 
                        Error();
                } 
                else 
                {  
                     ErrorNegativeNumber();      
                } 
            } 
            else 
                Error();
        } 
        else if (continueAnswer == "m") 
        {
            Menu();
        } 
        else if (continueAnswer == "n") 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
        } 
        else 
        {
            Error();
        }
    }

    public static void Menu() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

        string menu = @"Fresh Bread: $5 each (loaf)
        Delicious Pastry: $2 each

        ** Special of the week **
        Bread: Buy 2, get 1 free!
        Pastry: 3 for $5!";

        Console.WriteLine(menu);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");

        string menuAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

        Main();
    }

    public static void Error()  
    {
          Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
          Console.WriteLine("Error, Invalid Input");
          Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Restart");
          Console.ReadLine();

          Main();
    }

    public static void ErrorNegativeNumber() 
    {
          Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
          Console.WriteLine("Error, Invalid Input. Negative Input detected.  You owe us bread!");
          Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Restart");
          Console.ReadLine();

          Main();
    }
}
`````

Thank you so much for your help,  I know I can refactor my program.cs to make it more DRY.. but right now I'm just focused on using auto-implemented properties.

I got really confused on this one.. I hope I can get some help, thank you.

Comment: Fun fact: those `{get;set}` pairs are called *properties*. You dont have any of them either.  Also missing a question in your post.

Comment: I've posted an answer as I understand the question. I don't think this is off-topic for SO, though I think the question needs more clarity, but I do see an inkling of question here. The question I see, "How do I implement a constructor and a property on a class?'. [C# Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) ... [C# Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Comment: Fair enough.  I too like your ASCII art :)

Comment: I edited the title to include a question!  What great insight into the code as well as my communication skills.  I learned a lot from the edit and got to see what it looks like when I rush things! Thank you!

Comment: Be careful with all of those `ErrorX`/`Menu` methods that are recursively calling `Main`. Eventually the stack is going to overflow. Loops are one of the most basic constructs in programming, much more important (IMO) than constructors/properties/anything OO. I suggest you look into that before you go any further

Comment: thanks pinkfloyd! i dont know what it means that the stack is going to overflow.  I am in a bootcamp and hopefully that is a topic they will cover by the end.  I will look into it tho thanks.

Comment: You never return from your methods. You just keep calling them forever and ever. if you stuck a break point on the last brace of any of your methods, the break point would never be hit. Eventually you run out of stack space and program will crash. In your little app it would likely take a while since ur dealing with user input etc, but this pattern would crash pretty fast in a "normal" app

Comment: oh okay, i see what you mean.  I just wrote it like that in loops to get it to work.  i bet I could add a try catch block that solves this problem next project. 

https://github.com/FaisalRana/CSharp.Bakery check out my updated repo!

Answer (score 2):

Here's your `Bread` class with a constructor method and one property, `PricePerLoaf`. The constructor takes one argument, loaf price, and sets it to the `PricePerLoaf` property on instantiation of the object. The property is set to be readable from outside the class but only accessible for setting/writing from within the class, this helps protect the price from being set externally after the `Bread` class is created.

It doesn't make sense to pass the `numOfBread` value to the constructor as this value will change for each calculation, for this reason `numOfBread` stays as the argument for the `CalcBread` method. However, the `CalcBread` has a hard-coded value for the bread price. The bread price, `PricePerLoaf`, makes more sense to add as a constructor argument since it could change depending on the bread type/quality/etc.

```
public class Bread
{
        
    public Bread(int loafPrice)
    {
        // let's ensure a new bread object cannot be created with a price of $0 or less
        // we will throw an exception if the object is initialized with an invalid loaf price
        if(loafPrice <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(loafPrice));

        // here we set the PricePerLoaf property from the received constructor argument value
        PricePerLoaf = loafPrice;
    }

    // we create a property for the loaf price; the property can be read outside of this class
    // but can only be set by this class
    public int PricePerLoaf { get; private set; }

    public int CalcBread(int numOfBread)
    {
        // when we calculate the price we use our PricePerLoaf property and no longer use the local 
        // variable 'priceOfLoaf' that was hard coded here, this allows the price to change and different
        // Bread objects with different prices could be implemented (see usage example below)
        if (numOfBread % 3 == 0)
        {
            return (numOfBread * PricePerLoaf) - ((numOfBread / 3) * PricePerLoaf);
        }
        else if (numOfBread % 3 == 1)
        {
            return (numOfBread * PricePerLoaf) - ((numOfBread - 1) / 3 * PricePerLoaf);
        }
        else if (numOfBread % 3 == 2)
        {
            return (numOfBread * PricePerLoaf) - ((numOfBread - 2) / 3 * PricePerLoaf);
        }
        else
        {
            return numOfBread * PricePerLoaf;
        }
    }
}
```

How you could use the new Bread class...

```
int numOfBread = 10;
Bread cheapBread = new Bread(3);
int cheapBreadPrice = cheapBread.CalcBread(numOfBread);

Bread freshBread = new Bread(5);
int freshBreadPrice = freshBread.CalcBread(numOfBread);

Bread gourmetBread = new Bread(8);
int gourmetBreadPrice = gourmetBread.CalcBread(numOfBread);

Console.WriteLine($"Cheap Bread Price = ${cheapBreadPrice}");
Console.WriteLine($"Fresh Bread Price = ${freshBreadPrice}");
Console.WriteLine($"Gourmet Bread Price = ${gourmetBreadPrice}");
```

The output would be...

```
Cheap Bread Price = $21
Fresh Bread Price = $35
Gourmet Bread Price = $56
```

Comment: I was able to implement some of the changes you suggested.  
I had to do one thing different from your code, and that was to use this.PricePerLoaf when defining the field in the Bread() Constructor.  

I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your information.  Here is the solution I came up with :).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bakery.Models
{
    public class Bread
    { 
      
      public int PricePerLoaf { get; private set; }
      public int BreadPrice { get;set; }
      public Bread()
      {
        PricePerLoaf = 5;
        BreadPrice = 0;
      }
       public void CalcBread(int numOfBread) {
          if(numOfBread % 3 == 0) 
          {
            BreadPrice = (numOfBread * PricePerLoaf) - ((numOfBread/3) * PricePerLoaf);     
          } else if(numOfBread % 3 == 1) 
          {
            BreadPrice = (numOfBread * PricePerLoaf) - ((numOfBread-1)/3 * PricePerLoaf);
          } else if (numOfBread % 3 == 2) 
          {
            BreadPrice = (numOfBread * PricePerLoaf) - ((numOfBread-2)/3 *PricePerLoaf);
          } else BreadPrice = numOfBread * PricePerLoaf;
     }
         
    }
}
```

Let me know what you think!

https://github.com/FaisalRana/CSharp.Bakery